# Enabling App SandBox lead to a Crash when getting UserDefault Dictionary Value

Tags: swift, macos, nsuserdefaults

I have tested with the debugger and both the `Dictionary` and the `value` I am interested in are not nil. When I enable the App `Sandbox` the app crashes, but when I disable it everything works ok. Is there something to do when using UserDefaults with `Sandbox` enabled?

Code where the crash occurs:

```
func getPreferenceSettings(_ aKey: String) -> Bool
{
  var lastPreferenceSetting: Bool!
  if let currentSetting: Dictionary<String, Bool> = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "defaultValues") as? Dictionary<String,Bool>{
    lastPreferenceSetting = currentSetting[aKey]! //crash at this line
  }else{
    //show error to the user
  }
  return lastPreferenceSetting
}
```

I am using Xcode 9.4

Comment: Obviously `currentSettings` has no value for the key `aKey`. Avoid using `!` and safely unwrap.

Comment: Do not declare `lastPreferenceSetting` as an implicitly unwrapped `Bool`. It would be better, in this case, to declare it as a normal `Bool` with an initial value.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @rmaddy I have changed below the return type from Bool? as was initially and make `lastPreferenceSetting` optional because because the value could be `True` or `False` and i think  it's not correct in this case to assign it a default value but instead unwrapping it when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

The key value was nil (i was using the Release schemes instead of the Debug, that is why i was not able to see its value and assumed it was not nil). Also with the help of the debugger i was able to see that the key was never saved in the dictionary. The strange thing is that when disabling the `Sandbox` the crash doesn't occur. I have modified the method in the following way so it returns an optional and then the caller checks with `optional binding` if there is a key or not.

```
func getPreferenceSettings(_ aKey: String) -> Bool?
{
  var lastPreferenceSetting: Bool?
  if let currentSetting: Dictionary<String, Bool> = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "defaultValues") as? Dictionary<String,Bool>{
    lastPreferenceSetting = currentSetting[aKey]
  }else{
    //show error to the user
  }
  return lastPreferenceSetting
}
```

**EDIT**

@vadian

1. I was reading when to use correctly the `?` type and it's commonly used to indicate the absence of a value for example the mid name of a Person. But in this case the preference property is always present in the project because it's hard coded by the developer (except, like happened to me when i forgot to add it to the `UserDefaults` and had first to clear it before update the dictionary with the new key ). If i understand correctly, from what you have write, i should return an `Bool?` value and then check with `optional binding` in the caller method if it's `nil` or not; this should be done not only for the mid name case for the user side but also for the developer side because there could be another developer that could pass a wrong `aKey`, right?
2. Also is it correct to declare the `lastPreferenceSetting` as `?`, because if i use a default value and the `if let` evaluate to false, the function could return not the expected value.

Comment: This makes no difference. If `aKey` does not exist or the `if let` evaluates to `false` the code will crash.

Comment: @vadian i have updated my doubts and the code above, thank you for your time :)

Comment: After your edit my comment makes no sense anymore. In case of a `Bool` an absent value can be treated as `false` as it does when you get a `Bool` value from `UserDefaults` with `bool(forKey:`. An alternative (and recommended by Apple) is to **register** all default values before using them.

Comment: @vadian An absent value should not be treated in my case with `false` because i am also using false to disable the checkbox of the corresponding preference property. Instead when the user checks the preference property, its value will be `true` and some actions will be executed. So if there is no dictionary or key i should check if this is the case (with optional binding) and if so i shouldn't execute any operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if both keys `defaultValues` and `aKey` exist. As the return value is non-optional return `false` as default value.

This code uses the dedicated method `dictionary(forKey`

```
func getPreferenceSettings(_ aKey: String) -> Bool
{
  if let currentSetting = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "defaultValues"),
     let lastPreferenceSetting = currentSetting[aKey] as? Bool {
        return lastPreferenceSetting
  } else {
      //show error to the user
  }
  return false
}
```